# Querying Database table having number

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I have to query the database table which has certain number within its name.

my table name: Machine_001_Items.

My query:

```
insert into Machine_001_Items(x,y,z,a) 
  VALUES(" + aa + "," + bb+ ","+ cc+","+dd+") 
    SELECT scope_identity()
```

however, I get error saying: "Incorrect syntax near 01".

Please help, I am not able to fix this.

Comment: `scope_identity()` would indicate sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Try this ie, use the single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
insert into Machine_001_Items(x,y,z,a) 
  VALUES(' + aa + ',' + bb+ ','+ cc+','+dd+')
```

Comment: My exact query is ExecuteQuery("insert into Machine_001_Items(x,y,z,a) 
  VALUES(" + aa + "," + bb+ ","+ cc+","+dd+") 
    SELECT scope_identity()", connection);

Comment: @user3483952:- Try to replace the query with the one which I answered ie, use this query: `ExecuteQuery("insert into Machine_001_Items(x,y,z,a) 
  VALUES(' + aa + ',' + bb+ ','+ cc+','+dd+')  SELECT scope_identity()", connection); `

Comment: sorry problem still exisit

Comment: @user3483952:- Did you try to execute the same query on query analyzer?

Comment: @user3483952:- Also check this: `ExecuteQuery("insert into [Machine_001_Items](x,y,z,a) VALUES(' + aa + ',' + bb+ ','+ cc+','+dd+') SELECT scope_identity()", connection);`

Comment: in analyzer its working fine, but in my console application code its not

Comment: @user3483952:- You need to provide some more details as the above code is working in analyzer so I guess the issue is somewhere else. A wild guess although did you try to remove the select scope_identity part somethng like this: `ExecuteQuery("insert into Machine_001_Items(x,y,z,a) VALUES(' + aa + ',' + bb+ ','+ cc+','+dd+') ", connection);`